# Named Credential Authentication

Tags: callout, apexrest, namedcredentials, website-integration, xero

I am trying to connect with Xero using Named Credentials. I am using oAuth2.0 authentication protocol.

I have created a Auth. Provider and Named credentials as shown in the image below
[image]

[image]

The Named Credentials Authentication Status is showing as pending. How to make it authenticated?

I have checked "Start Authentication Flow on Save" but once i hit on save i am getting this url "https://login.xero.com/identity/error?errorId" and error code 500.

I think i am missing some steps. Please help.

Quick Update : Call back url i have in auth provider in Salesforce and in Xero connected app are different. Can it be the reason?

Thanks,
Soumen

Comment: did you check `Start Authentication flow on Save`??

Comment: @rahulgawale : Yes i did that. But i am getting https://login.xero.com/identity/error?errorId , Error Code -500. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: I have updated the question details. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by using same callback URL at both the places.
Thank you all for your help!